# 'Knowing' a stative verb?

Tags: verbs, stative-verbs

> They might not be knowing it.

Is 'knowing' a verb here? If yes, why is it considered a stative verb if it has a progressive meaning?

> This is why I said knowing the meaning of it is hard.

Also here is another example using 'knowing'.

Comment: [Stative verbs](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/stative-verbs) describe a state rather than an action. **They aren't usually used in the present continuous form.** So it's *I don't know the answer*, NOT *I'm not knowing the answer. She really likes you*, NOT *She's really liking you. He seems happy at the moment*, NOT *He's seeming happy at the moment.* What exactly don't you understand about this?

Comment: Ok so are both examples grammatically wrong? But the second one is very similar to a phrasing in CGEL.

Comment: There's a huge difference between constructions that ***aren't usually used*** and constructions that are actually ***ungrammatical**!* Your first example *(They might not be knowing it)* would be extremely unidiomatic in any context I can think of (but someone else might be able to come up with a context where it's perfectly okay). The second example *(This is why I said knowing the meaning of it is hard)* is an "unusual" thing to say (I'd prefer *...why I said it is hard **to know** the meaning*), but it's a very different construction where "continuous stative verb" simply isn't an issue.

Comment: "They might not be knowing it" sounds very Inglish for "They might not know it".

Comment: "knowing the meaning of it" is not a verb, as it were. It is a noun phrase. "Knowing about a situation doesn't mean doing something about it."

Comment: FumbleFingers astutely reserves the possibility for a grammatical use. Maybe: A: Let’s hire Mary. She knows Python and knowing it is crucial. B: (facetiously) Well, from the looks of what she showed us, she might not be knowing it. Where B’s reply is so intended, it seems reasonable to characterize it as natural and felicitous. On the other hand, one could play with the language for some effect, such as humor, and similarly say anything: “Me so confused!” I wonder if there’s a term for acceptable use of the (otherwise?) ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> <sup>?</sup>They might not be knowing it.

Because *to know* is stative, the sentence above is at least questionable, if not simply unacceptable.

> This is why I said that knowing the meaning of it is hard.

This sentence is acceptable.

There is a difference.

In the first example, "might not be knowing" is a predicating phrase.  This "knowing" is traditionally called *the main verb*.  When stative verbs are used as *main* verbs, that's when the progressive form doesn't make sense.

In the second, "knowing the meaning of it" is the subject of its clause.  Traditionally, this is called a *gerund phrase*.  The *-ing* verb forms do make sense in gerund phrases and participial phrases -- pretty much whenever it is *not* the *main* verb.

That's how a native speaker might learn to recognize a stative verb.  It's when the *-ing* form doesn't intuitively make sense as a main verb.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically wrong

In the second sentence, ''knowing'' is a gerund. A gerund is a noun made from verb + -ing and it can function as subject, object... [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/)

Know is generally a stative verb but some stative verbs can occasionally be used with its dynamic form as well  [BBC Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-5/session-1)

Comment: But there *is* such a form as "might not be" + v-ing: "She might not be sleeping". The problem is that "know" is a stative verb, so cannot have a continuous form. "Be knowing" is a continuous form. "Know" is not an exception to those rules

Answer (score 0):

***KNOW*** is a Stative verb but sometimes (very rarely, giving rise to acceptability issue) it does combine with prograssive under certain circumstances. It happens with other Stative verbs as well, so thinking that a Stative verb never occurs in progressive is not always right. (So I always read the Stative meaning and Dynamic meaning, and a verb can shift between these two categories)

> **1.** Because I am not a crime negotiator. I don't have any expertise in this. There are people who will talk to both the hostages and the
> person holding them hostage, and they will be ***knowing*** what to
> deal with and how to resolve the situation, hopefully, peacefully.
> [SPOKEN Source - CNN Period: 2014]
>
> **2.** There are a lot of great things that come with being a Masters champion, " he said. " But the best of them all may be ***knowing***
> you get to come back to Augusta and play every year for as long as you
> can walk the golf course. " [NEWS Source - Washington Post Period -
> 2006]
>
> **3.** He was Little John at home, Gator John on wheels, John Jude on his birth certificate, Goofy-Foot John, or simply the Kine to those in
> the know. He would also be ***knowing*** John, or that's what he
> promised his mother. [FICTION Source - American Taliban by Abraham,
> Pearl Period - 2010]
>
> **4.** So what's wrong with him? - I will be ***knowing*** in one moment. [TV Source - Lilo & Stitch: The Series Period - 2003]
>
> **5.** She must be ***knowing*** Amar Damji's whereabouts.  [MOVIE Source - The 1995 NCLR Bravo Awards Period - 1995]

Generally when Stative verbs combine with progressive it shows a difference in meaning making them dynamic, and still there are some verbs like *KNOW* that don't necessarily change the meaning to be dynamic and be in progressive. In *Understanding English Grammar* by *Thomas E Payne* on page no 148 it states *KNOW* is somewhat agentive. And so it can be progressive.

In your sentence, ***KNOW*** is a verb.

> They might not be ***knowing*** it.

Another similar example:

> Most of the eNotes debaters might be ***knowing*** that I am a Muslim, though not from US, but I am sure that the Muslim community of US will be more than pleased to cooperate in this endeavour.

Yes this sentence is fine. [MY NOTE: this type of *might be knowing* is common in Indian English]

Your other sentence:

> This is why I said ***knowing*** the meaning of it is hard.

is also correct but it has different construction. It is part of a non-finite clause, but yes it is also a verb in there. Here whether the verb is stative or dynamic in nature doesn't pose any problem. That non finite clause is called Gerund-Participle clause.

Comment: Knowing in the second sentence is a gerund **noun**; "Knowing the meaning of something can be tricky.". See it now? :) It is neither a verb nor is it dynamic.

Comment: @Lambie a noun doesn't take another Noun Phrase as complement as far as I can remember. Moreover the other answer also says it's a verb.

Comment: Knowing the answer is important. That is a gerund noun.

Comment: @Lambie as far as I remember it is not. It is still a verb.

Comment: A gerund phrase consists of a gerund [verbal functioning as a noun] plus modifier(s), object(s), and/or complement(s). So, knowing = gerund and "the meaning of it" is a complement of it. https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/index.html

Comment: @Lambie Though I don't follow this school of grammar, but I understand what it says. It still says it's verbal but functions as noun. (Though a noun functions in many different ways). So is it wrong to assert that *knowing* is a verb?

Comment: It is a gerund (formed from a verb) with a direct object. It does not act as a verb in the sentence, as in: I know him, I know you. It functions like this: Knowing the answer is fun.  And H&P grammar doesn't really interest me.

Comment: @Lambie ot is stilll a verb but it acts as a noun, as you say. But that doesn't make it a noun. Does it? Acting as a noun is very loose statement. Like a noun can act like a time adjunct like *I will write him tomorrow* here *tomorrow* is a noun but it functions as a time adjunct, which in your terminology it is a noun but acts as an adverb, right? But this doesn't make *tomorrow* an adverb, it is still a noun. Gerund doesn't function like that, though a noun does.

Comment: (cont...) Another occasion, a Noun can be a head in a phrase structure, and an adjective can pre-modify it, but Gerund doesn't occur in that waynin a sentence

Comment: If you think that this: **Playing football** is fun. has the verb playing, we have nothing else to say to one another. It is the subject of the sentence, NOT the verb in the sentence and it is a noun gerund. The only verb in that sentence is "is".

Comment: @Lambie of course that is a subject. A clause can be a subject just like a phrase can. But my point is internal to the subordinate clause *play* is still a verb.

Comment: Lambie is right here. A gerund is also called a verbal noun. An [adj] x is an x!